# Dimension of a subspace smaller than dimension of intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose I have a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, and $U_1, U_2$ are subspaces of $V$, such that $U_1\nsubseteq U_2$.

Is it possible that $\dim{U_1}\leq\dim{U_1 \cap U_2}$?

Comment: $U_{1} \cap U_{2}$ is a subspace of $U_{1}$ so it will always be true that $dim(U_{1}) \geq dim(U_{1} \cap U_{2})$. If you have equality it means $U_{1} \cap U_{2} = U_{1}$ which would contradict your hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $\dim (U_1 \oplus U_2) = \dim U_1 + \dim U_2 - \dim(U_1 \cap U_2)$. Hence, $$\dim U_1 = \dim(U_1 \cap U_2) \implies \dim U_2 = \dim (U_1 \oplus U_2) \implies U_1 \subset U_2.$$

Comment: Why does $U_1 \nsubseteq U_2$ mean that $\dim{V} = \dim{U_1} + \dim{U_2} - dim{U_1\cap U_2}$? If $V = \mathbb{R}^3, U_1 = Span([1,0,0]), U_2 = Span([0,1,0])$?

Comment: Sorry, I should have written $V = U_1 \oplus U_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Fact: If $X$ is a subspace of the finite dimensional vector space $Y,$ and $\dim X = \dim Y,$ then $X=Y.$ Hence if $\dim U_1 \le \dim U_1\cap U_2,$ then $\dim U_1 = \dim U_1\cap U_2,$ hence $U_1\cap U_2$ equals $U_1.$ This implies $U_1 \subset U_2,$ contradiction.